# Can I add rows to Output Buffer in SSIS Script Component in PostExecute?

Tags: ssis, script-component

I have a Script Component where I buffer all the rows, then do some processing, and then I want to create the output rows. I tried accessing the Output Buffer object in PostExecute but apparently that's not possible? Gives "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" error when it hits AddRow(). Is there a way to do this?

```
 public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();

    //processing

    foreach(ChartValue cv in chartValues)
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.usedcl = cv.Centerline;
        //etc
    }           
}
```

Comment: Yes, you only have access to output rows in `Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)`. This might seem like a problem, but always there are ways around it. I couldn't quite understand what you are going to do in your code.

Comment: Are you in synchronous mode (default) or did you filp it to asynchronous mode? Was the Script created as a transformation or a destination?

Comment: It's Transformation and it's in asynchronous mode. There could be a way around it, it would just be so much easier if I could add to the output from PostExecute. Maybe if I get a count of the rows beforehand, I suppose I would know in ProcessInputRow that I'm on the last row and then do the final processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Kelly for your example. But like H B said the `base.Input0_ProcessInput()` calls `Input0_ProcessInputRow` for every row. And in my case `Buffer.EndOfRowset()` is false always. So I make the shorter code:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
{
    base.Input0_ProcessInput(Buffer); // operate rows in while loop

     //when done collecting all rows, do calculations
    CalculateResults();
}
```

Comment: This is not entirely correct. `Input0_ProcessInput` can be called multiple times, you must include the check for `Buffer.EndOfRowset()`. (for small datasets this will do just fine though)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no, you can't do that but easy solution: add the ProcessInput function to loop through each row using the ProcessInputRow function (the function that is already included) and use EndOfRowset to know when you are done, then you can do the final processing code.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
{
    base.Input0_ProcessInput(Buffer);

    try
    {
        //loop through each row
        while (Buffer.NextRow())
        {
             Input0_ProcessInputRow(Buffer);
        }

        //when done collecting all rows, do calculations
        if (Buffer.EndOfRowset())
        {
            CalculateResults();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       //code here
    }
}

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{ 
     //gather each row's values and put into List for processing at the end
```

Comment: This code should work, but I believe you don't need to loop through each row if you call `base.Input0_ProcessInput(Buffer);`. Just `if (Buffer.EndOfRowset())
        {
            CalculateResults();
        }` will suffice after calling the base method. This code also works, but your while loop will never do any of the row processing.

Comment: Are you saying you don't think the while loop isn't doing anything? It's just skipping over it (not finding a next row)?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. Because the Buffer contents have already been processed entirely by `base.Input0_ProcessInput(Buffer);`
This base method internally also calls `Input0_ProcessInputRow` for each row so it's hard to tell the difference (without debugging).